# force margin: 0px to all child elements, is it possible?

Tags: css

Is it possible to force a behavior and ignore css in child DIVs ?

I want to remove all margins that are childs of a top DIV... but only this DIV childs

Btw I need this because I cannot get to the real CSS i need to inject something that cancels the behaviour (margins) i wanna erase.

```
<DIV>
   <DIV class="no_margin">
      <DIV class="has_margin"> </DIV> // this one has a margin, and should lose it
   </DIV>
</DIV>
<DIV class="has_margin"> </DIV> // should not lose margin
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do any of these:

- `.no_margin .has_margin { margin: 0 }`
- `.no_margin div { margin: 0 }`
- `.no_margin * { margin: 0 }`

And you could add `!important` if the priority isn't high enough, like `margin: 0 !important`.

Example http://jsfiddle.net/9yx6B/

Answer (score 2):

use !important

```
.no_margin *{
    margin:0!important;
}
```